# Append if last line not equal

Tags: c++, file, unit-testing, stream

I want to write a function which does this: given a file and a name (string), append to the file if the last line is not 'name' (create the file if the file is not there). Otherwise just do nothing. I can certainly create a function like this:

```
appendIfLastLineNotEqual(file fd, string name) { ... }
```

However, this will be hard to write unit test as it dumps to file. Is there a cleaner way to do this, as well as easy to unit test? Also I can do file parsing backward etc to implement the function. Any smart way instead of reading the file, compare with the last line etc? Thanks!

Comment: Post a [MCVE] ..

Answer (score 1):

If you can can use streams as input parameter to your function, your code will work with whatever stream you provide.

You can use `std::fstream` as input in your production code, and instead use `std::sstream`  or even create your own mockup of a stream in your unit test code.